# Getting jinja looped divs to stack vertically

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I have a jinja loop, and I want a page break after each iteration (after `{{ detail[2] }}` ). But for some reason, each interation keeps stacking to the right of the one that came before. I've tried adding `<br>` inside the loop, I created a wrapper div (commentwrap), I added `page-break-after: always` and `page-break-after: always` to the CSS ... But I can't get it working.

**CSS**

```
.fbpic {
  float:left;
}

.votecomment {
    float:left;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 13px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d9d9d9;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    page-break-after: always;
}

.commentwrap {
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="commentloop">
{% for detail in vote_details %}
    <div class="commentwrap">
        <div class="fbpic">
            <img src="{{ detail[3] }}" style="width:40px;border-radius:50%;">
        </div>
        <div class="votecomment">
            <strong> {{ detail[0] }} </strong>&nbsp; <strong>Vote:</strong> {{ detail[1] }} &nbsp; <strong>Comments:</strong> {{ detail[2] }}<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out after I typed the question --- turns out `float:left;` was messing with it. I used padding instead to get the effect I wanted. There's probably a better way, but this worked.